# Youtube embed video not showing at all

Tags: html

Can someone help me with this code? The YouTube video isn't showing up at all.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"> </iframe>
```

Comment: it's working... check https://jsfiddle.net/rwa5ss2c/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other issue eg. server policy etc. can you provide any other info